# When settlement criteria of a foundation is satisfied, bearing criteria is also automatically satisfied?

Tags: structural-engineering, structures, geotechnical-engineering, soil-mechanics

We design the foundations to settlement criteria than bearing correct? Because settlement criteria is stricter? I mean, can there be an example where the settlement criteria is satisfied but bearing is not? Can you think of such example? If not, then checking bearing would be redundant?

Comment: Clay may not settle very much and so meet that criteria, but will it support much?

Comment: This does not answer anything, plus clay settles one of the most. In fact, you are asking a question yourself too.

Comment: That was a comment, not an answer and designed as such to hopefully make you think a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Structural engineers are not necessarily experts in soil science. For gravity loads, the limit state for foundation soil bearing stress is excessive settlement. Therefore, the allowable soil bearing stress given in the geotechnical report should have considered any maximum settlement specification. In any case, soil bearing must be calculated and compared with the allowable bearing. If the Geotech gives you more than one value, check them all.